# How to convert passphrase to AES256 key?

Tags: encryption, hash, aes

My plan is to convert a passphrase in UTF-8 ASCII-US to Unit8Array(32) then use it in:

`256bitsKey =  Unit8Array(32)` from passphase

```
iv = window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(32));

CryptoJS.enc.encrypt(data, 256bitsKey , {iv: iv});
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: "Key Derivation Functions" is the term you are looking for. Look up [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)

Comment: [Argon2id](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2) is the state of the art for key derivation from a password. PBKDF2 is an old standard.

Comment: @A.Hersean Yeah, right. I couldn't remember the name of Argon2 and I couldn't be bothered to look it up, so I just put in PBKDF. I guess that's a bad thing to do when giving security advice though...

Comment: @nobody very bad... you should have gone with key derivation and let the OP search current standard

Comment: I guess the huge advantage of PBKDF2 is its name. Because when you look at the algorithm, it's not that good.

Comment: curious: why use CryptoJS when there's a built-in crypto API?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Web Crypto API's [window.crypto.subtle.deriveBits()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/deriveBits) function to derive a key from a password, and return a Unit8Array containing the derived key.  Here is an example:

```
var password='p4$$w0rd';
var pbkdf2iterations=10000;
var passphrasebytes=new TextEncoder("utf-8").encode(password);
var pbkdf2salt=window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(8));

window.crypto.subtle.importKey('raw', passphrasebytes, {name: 'PBKDF2'}, false, ['deriveBits'])
.then(function(result) {
    var passphrasekey=result;
    return pbkdf2bytes=window.crypto.subtle.deriveBits({"name": 'PBKDF2', "salt": pbkdf2salt, "iterations": pbkdf2iterations, "hash": 'SHA-256'}, passphrasekey, 256)       
}).then(function(result) {  
    pbkdf2bytes=new Uint8Array(result);
    console.log(pbkdf2bytes);
});
```